# Kubernetes Pods Restart Notification alerts on my team's channel

Tags: kubernetes, microsoft-teams, azure-aks

My Pods are running on AKS Cluster. Whenever my pods restarted, I had to get a notification on my team's channel, are there any articles or commands to configure the notification?

Comment: Hey, Incoming Webhook allows any external apps to send notification in Teams channels. Please refer- [Webhooks & connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors) and [Create Incoming Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)

Answer (score 2):

For that same, you can use tools or application like **botkube** : https://www.botkube.io/

Also check the **Kubewatch** : https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch

You can also implement the **Grafana** with the **Prometheus** and **Alert manager** for monitoring and getting the alert system. : https://github.com/grafana-operator/grafana-operator

However if you can not looking for any tools or applications you can write down the custom script of python, node or any language you are good with and monitor any pod restart event and send the slack hook event.

Sharing one example python code with check the POD running or crashing and send a notification to slack you can update the logic as per need.

```
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
import json
import requests
import time
logger = logging.getLogger('k8s_events')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# If running inside pod
#config.load_incluster_config()

# If running locally
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
v1ext = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api() 

w = watch.Watch()

mydict={}

webhook_url = '';

while True:
    pod_list= v1.list_namespaced_pod("default");
    for i in pod_list.items:
        for c in i.status.container_statuses:
            if(c.ready == True):
                if i.metadata.name in mydict:
                    print("Inside mydict If");
                    print("Pod updated : ",i.metadata.name);
                    print("My dict value : ",mydict);
                    mydict[i.metadata.name]['end_time'] = i.status.conditions[1].last_transition_time;
                    dt_started = mydict[i.metadata.name]['start_time'].replace(tzinfo=None);
                    dt_ended = mydict[i.metadata.name]['end_time'].replace(tzinfo=None);
                    duration = str((dt_ended - dt_started).total_seconds()) + ' Sec';
                    fields =  [{"title": "Status", "value": "READY", "short": False }, {"title": "Pod name", "value": i.metadata.name, "short": False }, {"title": "Duration", "value": duration, "short": False }, {"title": "Service name", "value": c.name, "short": False } ]
                    if c.name not in ('conversation-auto-close-service-scheduler','admin-service-trail-fllow-up-scheduler','bot-trial-email-scheduler','conversation-service-scheduler','faq-service-scheduler','nlp-service-scheduler','refresh-add-on-scheduler','response-sheet-scheduler'):
                        text = c.name + " Pod is started"; 
                        data = {"text": text, "mrkdwn": True, "attachments" : [{"color": "#FBBC05", "title": "Pod Details", "fields" : fields, "footer": "Manvar", "footer_icon": "https://cdn.test.manvar.com/assets/manvar-icon.png"}, ], }
                        print("Final data to post: ",data);
                        response = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data),headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                        del mydict[i.metadata.name]
                        if response.status_code != 200:
                            raise ValueError('Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s' % (response.status_code, response.text));
                time.sleep(1);
            else:
                mydict[i.metadata.name] = {"start_time": i.status.conditions[0].last_transition_time,"end_time": i.status.conditions[1].last_transition_time};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out Botkube but I did not want to publicly expose my cluster endpoint, so I wrote the following script based on the code from @Harsh Manvar. You can connect this to Teams using the Incoming Webhook Teams app from Microsoft.

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import json
import requests
import time


def monitorNamespace(namespace: str, webhookUrl: str):
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    pod_list= v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace);
    podsNotRunning = {"Namespace": namespace, "Pods": []}

    for pod in pod_list.items:
        status = getPodStatus(pod)        
        if status != "Running":
            podsNotRunning["Pods"].append({"Podname": pod.metadata.name, "status": status})  

    if len(podsNotRunning)>0:
        sendAlert(podsNotRunning, webhookUrl)


def sendAlert(podsNotRunning, webhookUrl):
    print(podsNotRunning)
    response = requests.post(webhookUrl, data=json.dumps(podsNotRunning),headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Response error:', response) 


def getPodStatus(pod: client.models.v1_pod.V1Pod) -> str: 
    status = pod.status.phase 
    containerStatus = pod.status.container_statuses[0]
    if containerStatus.started is False or containerStatus.ready is False:
        waitingState = containerStatus.state.waiting
        if waitingState.message is not None:
            status = waitingState.reason  

    return status

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # If running inside pod:
    #config.load_incluster_config()
    # If running locally:
    config.load_kube_config()

    
    webhookUrl = 'http://webhookurl'
    namespace='default
    interval = 10

    while True:                 
        monitorNamespace(namespace, webhookUrl)           
        time.sleep(interval)
```